# css transparent block through the dark parent

Tags: html, css

I have two blocks with absolute. One is at the bottom, which overlaps the entire screen, the other is his child, which is on top of it. I need that the parent does not overlap the child, so that in the place where the child is, there is a completely transparent area.

now:
[image]
I need this
[image]
any ideas ?

```
<div className="helper">
    sdsad
    <div className="test"></div>
  </div>



 .helper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  z-index: 50;
}

.test {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  opacity: .3;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: A cut-out like appearance can be achieved by using either a CSS mask, clip-paths (can be complicated since you basically need an inverted clip path), or draw a custom SVG overlaying the page.

Comment: @Terry beat me to it... Read this: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/

Comment: Alternatively I came across [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ultKh) when trying to achieve a similar effect that uses box-shadow.

Comment: Both options are good, but the shadow is easier, thanks!